need setting up libreswan l2tp/ipsec vpn client on openwrt
i need some help settingup and initiating an LT2P/IPSEC vpn connection from my openwrt router. I am trying to connect to my work VPN in order to:

use some IP phones with my work extensions i have setup at home whilst i work from home.
use network shares/drives

my system details are:

Linksys E4200 (has an internet uplink port for wan, and 4 bridged ethernet ports and two wifi modules for lan)
OpenWrt 23.05.4 (r24012-d8dd03c46f)
Libreswan 4.12-1
xl2tpd 1.3.18-1
xfrm 4
vti 5
ppp 2.4.9.git-2021-01-04-4

eveything i have tried (from guides Openthreat, OpenWrt, Libreswan wiki) has not worked and now i need some community help.

This is my ipsec.conf file:
config setup
    # needed when using PSK only. Not needed for X.509 based servers
    uniqueids=no
    virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v4:100.64.0.0/10,%v4:!100.64.0.0/24

    logfile=/var/log/pluto.log
    plutodebug=all

conn vpn
    auto=start
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ike

    ikev2=insist
    #ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
    #ike=aes128-sha1-modp2048
    ikelifetime=86400s
    authby=secret

    pfs=yes
    phase2alg=aes256-sha1
    #esp=aes128-sha1-modp2048!
    #esp=aes256-sha1-dh5
    #esp=aes256-sha256!

    mtu=1400
    rekey=no

    left=%defaultroute
    leftnexthop=%defaultroute
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    #leftid=192.168.1.135

    right=VPN_SERVER_ID
    rightsubnet= 0.0.0.0/0
    rightnexthop=%defaultroute
    rightprotoport=17/1701
    rightid=10.0.0.70


this is the output i get when i run ipsec auto --up
181 "vpn" #12: initiating IKEv2 connection
181 "vpn" #12: sent IKE_SA_INIT request to VPN_SERVER_ID:500
003 "vpn" #12: dropping unexpected IKE_SA_INIT message containing NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notification; message payloads: N; missing payloads: SA,KE,Ni
010 "vpn" #12: STATE_V2_PARENT_I1: retransmission; will wait 0.5 seconds for response
003 "vpn" #12: dropping unexpected IKE_SA_INIT message containing NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notification; message payloads: N; missing payloads: SA,KE,Ni
010 "vpn" #12: STATE_V2_PARENT_I1: retransmission; will wait 1 seconds for response
003 "vpn" #12: dropping unexpected IKE_SA_INIT message containing NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notification; message payloads: N; missing payloads: SA,KE,Ni
010 "vpn" #12: STATE_V2_PARENT_I1: retransmission; will wait 2 seconds for response
003 "vpn" #12: dropping unexpected IKE_SA_INIT message containing NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notification; message payloads: N; missing payloads: SA,KE,Ni
010 "vpn" #12: STATE_V2_PARENT_I1: retransmission; will wait 4 seconds for response
003 "vpn" #12: dropping unexpected IKE_SA_INIT message containing NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notification; message payloads: N; missing payloads: SA,KE,Ni


Let me know if you need any additional information to help. I'm doing this over ssh as openwrt doesn't have an interface for setting up L2TP/IPSec VPN connections.
